# Displaying images in webpage without src URL

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, unicode

Recently i learned that i can display images in a web page without referencing an image URL as follows :

```
<img class="disclosure" img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAADgkQYQAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9oIGRQbOY8MjgMAAABVSURBVBjTfc6xDcAwCETRM0rt5nbA+49j70DDAqSLsGXyJQqkVxxwNOeMiEA+waW1VuT/inrvG7wikht8UETy2ygVMjO4O8YYTf6AqrZyUwYlygAAXo+QLmeF4c4uAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
```

I had another small bmp image that i wanted to display, so i opened it in vim and the img source looke like:
[image] 
When i paste this code where it needs to be pasted i only get "BMڀ"

- How to i convert/paste this code properly to be used as an image source?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to encode it in Base64

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Also you have to change (png) in...

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,
```

according to image filetype.

Here is a little PHP function, haven't tested it.

```
function encode64($file){
    $extension = explode(".", $file);
    $extension = end($extension);

    $binary = fread(fopen($file, "r"), filesize($file));

    return '<img src="data:image/'.$extension.';base64,'.base64_encode($binary).'"/>';
}

echo encode64("test.bmp");
```

2.

```
    function encode64($file){
        $binary = fread(fopen($file, "r"), filesize($file));
        return(base64_encode($binary));
    }

echo '<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,'.encode64("test.bmp").'"/>';
```

Tested my second function... works great... http://debconf11.com/so.php

Comment: Thanks!  I dont seem to be able to set any dimensions via CSS or tag attributes, is that possible with this method?  What is this representation of the image called anyway?

Comment: Of course, but then you have to set image type manually. Look in my answer.

Comment: While this is a useful answer that shows the principles at work, it might make more sense to mark Gaby Petrioli's answer as the accepted answer, because it encourages reuse of pre-existing technologies rather that are likely tested and applicable whether or not one is using PHP.

Comment: On Windows, CertUtil is installed by default, and it's pretty simple: `CertUtil -encode input.png output.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You can use online utilities like

- http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data

or

- http://www.sveinbjorn.org/dataurlmaker

for the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Base64 encoding of your image, you can use [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/)'s `convert` command with the [`INLINE:` output format](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php?ImageMagick#pseudo).

For example:

```
convert YourImage.png INLINE:PNG:YourImage_base64.txt
```

Now all you have to do in your HTML page is add `<img src="` and `">` around the content of the "YourImage_base64.txt" file.

Or you can directly write it all to STDOUT and add it directly at the end of your HTML file:

```
echo "<img src=\"$(convert YourImage.png INLINE:PNG:-)\">" >> some.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The image data must be base64 encoded.