# Embedding a static image in html email

Tags: html, email

I have a requirement where in I have to to send an email to customer, I have an email template coming in from database (blob data). And there is an header image which should be displayed in the email when customer opens the email.

1. The image will not be available on server
2. The image will not be available online (i.e in any website online).

This image is a client header. How can I embed the static image without referring to any location or any online website.

Comment: Are you crafting the email message yourself, or are you using some library? What language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible by encoding the image in Base64

For more info see this [Displaying images in webpage without src URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528695/displaying-images-in-webpage-without-src-url)

Finally you will end up with something like this in your html message:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA.........very_long_string....." />
```

Comment: @user2431128 if an answer helps you don't forget you can UPVOTE it and/or mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to this problem is multipart [MIME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047). You add the image as a part of the email message and use a cid reference in the `<img>` tag.

However, you're probably using some library to send this email, in which case it probably has an API for creating multipart MIME messages.

Answer (score 0):

in case you don't want to load images from the server then only embeding of image with base64 can workout.

Please refer the link below for more reference.

http://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html